# Iphone Standbymode problem

Tags: iphone

I want to show an alertview for user ,When iphone goes to standby mode or power save mode...
Is there any delegate function ,Can we used?

Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance...........

Comment: Can you add more details? Do you want to prevent the phone from going to standby? What is the effect you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the UIApplication delegate method

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

It is called when the application transitions from an active state to an inactive state.